# About sequences

Tags: number-theory

One has taken some positive numbers and built a sequence: $a_1$ is the sum of the numbers; $a_2$ is the sum of the squares of the numbers, $a_3$ is the sum of the cubes of the numbers, etc. Could be so that before $a_5$ $ a_1>a_2>a_3>a_4 > a_5$ and after $a_5$ $a_5 < a_6 < a_7 <...$?

Comment: I would take two numbers $1-\epsilon _1, 1+\epsilon _2$ and try to tune the values of $\epsilon$s to meet the criteria.

Comment: And if it is not possible?

Comment: See [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5%5Ex%2B1.02%5Ex+for+x%3D1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

Comment: Your answer generalizes nicely.

Comment: @didgogns, how did you realise that these numbers are true?

Comment: Let $f(x)=a^x+b^x$, then $f'(5)=0$. I plotted $x^5 \log (x)$, realized that $a=0.5$ might work, found the proper value value of $b$ by wolframalpha.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing didgogns' 
nice solution,
if
$f(x)
=e^{-ax}+e^{bx}
=(e^{-a})^x+(e^b)^{x}
$,
where $a,b > 0$,
$f'(x)=-ae^{-ax}+be^{bx}$
so that $f(x)$
has a unique minimum when
$ae^{-ax}=be^{bx}$
or
$\ln a-ax=\ln b+bx$
or
$x
=\frac{\ln a-\ln b}{a+b}
=\frac{\ln (a/b)}{a+b}
=\frac1{b}\frac{\ln (a/b)}{a/b+1}
$.

By choosing $a$ and $b$ properly,
we can get $x$
to take on 
any desired value
so that $f$
decreases to there
and increases after.

For example,
if $a/b=e$ then
$x=\frac1{b}\frac{1}{e+1}$
so choosing
$b=\frac1{x(e+1)}$
and $a=be$ works.